# Dropdown in MVC is not loading the data on Edit Function which call by WCF Service

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5, wcf-data-services

Dropdown in MVC is not loading the data on Edit Function , while calling from the WCF Service, 
on the dropdown the whole country name is listing but , on loging the save data the drop downis not showing the selcted country , which is saved, please find the image attached

[image]

The following code in the index page on edit function click(only drop down value is not showing correctly)

```
 <form id="form">
   <fieldset id="SubmitForm">
     <div class="form-group">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, ViewBag.ListofCountries as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { @id = "DropDwnCountry", @class = "form-control" })
     </div>
</fieldset>
```

the code is the edit function

```
var Edit = function (UserID) {
        $("#ModelTitle").html("Update Record");
        $("#MyModal").modal();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/User/GetUserbyID?UserID=" + UserID,
        success: function (data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            $("#UserID").val(obj.UserID);
            $("#userCode").val(obj.UserCode);
            $("#userName").val(obj.Name);

            debugger;
            alert('1');
            //$("#DropDwnCountry option:selected").text(ViewBag.ListofCountries)
            $("#DropDwnCountry option:selected").val(obj.CountryID); //not loading the correct value
            alert(obj.CountryID);
            //alert($("#DropDwn").text(obj.CountryID));

        }
    })
}
```

the following code , in the controller

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
   Countries = new TktServiceClient().GetCountries().ToList();
   ViewBag.ListofCountries = new SelectList(Countries, "CountryID","CountryName" );
   return View();
 }
```

please help what was the error facing on this

Comment: If you send a Post request by using Postman, does the object contain CountryID property? Or, Does the entry in the database have CountryID property?

Comment: yes , the correct id is showing but the text is not showing

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this line

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID, ViewBag.ListofCountries as SelectList, "--Select Country--", new { @id = "DropDwnCountry", @class = "form-control" })

by

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryID,new SelectList(ViewBag.ListofCountries, "CountryID", "CountryName"),  "--Select Country--", new { @id = "DropDwnCountry", @class = "form-control" })

in the Index view

Comment: tried m error `DataBinding: 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectListItem' does not contain a property with the name 'CountryID'`.

Comment: yes you should have CountryId in the @modal called in ur view.                                  For example ----@model yourProjectName.Model.ViewModel-----.. do you have something like this in your view? u can call view model or a sample model as per ur case.

Comment: same error, i pass with `tuple` method to call both service object, same error